# How can I calculate $\int_{-5}^5 \dfrac{x^3 \sin^2x}{x^4+2x^2+1}~dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I was wondering what kind of approach could be used for this integration:
$$\int_{-5}^5 \dfrac{x^3 \sin^2x}{x^4+2x^2+1}~dx$$

Comment: It's an odd function.

Comment: I guess it comes from a wifi code.Are you a chinese student?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

Observe that the function is *odd* and the interval $[-5,5]$ is symmetric about $0$.

See more in this question:

[Definite integral of an odd function is 0 (symmetric interval)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1230999/9464)

Answer (score 1):

$$
x^4 + 2x^2 + 1 = \left(x^2+1\right)^2
$$
so we have an integral of the form
$$
\int \frac{x^3}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}\sin^2 x dx
$$
we can clearly see that 
$$
f(x) = \frac{x^3}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}\sin^2 x \implies f(-x) = -f(x)
$$
i.e. an Odd function
$$
\int_{-5}^5f(x)dx = \int_{-5}^0f(x)dx + \int_{0}^5 f(x)dx = \int_{5}^0 f(-x)(-dx) + \int_{0}^5 f(x)dx = \int_0^5f(-x)dx  + \int_{0}^5 f(x)dx 
$$
now the final bit is to use $f(-x) = -f(x)$ we obtain
$$
\int_{-5}^5f(x)dx  = -\int_0^5f(x)dx + \int_{0}^5 f(x)dx = 0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Once you notice it's an odd function,the answer will follow.

[definite integral of odd function](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definite_Integral_of_Odd_Function)