# Need help with this integral.

Tags: calculus, integration

Need help with this integral.

$\displaystyle \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin x \cos nx \, dx$ where $n\in\Bbb{N}$.

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: The functions $\sin k x$ and $\cos n x$ are orthogonal with this inner product, so the integral is always zero.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I figured to out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is an odd function, meaning $f(x) = -f(-x)$

$$\int_{-a}^{a} f(x)dx = 0.$$

Notice that $\sin(-x)\cos(-nx) = -\sin(x)\cos(nx)$ which means that $\sin(x)\cos(nx)$ is an odd function. Using $f(x) = \sin(-x)\cos(nx)$ and $a = \pi$ in the form above we get

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin(x)\cos(nx)dx = 0.$$

To break it down even further we can use

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin(x)\cos(nx)dx = \int_{-\pi}^{0} \sin(x)\cos(nx)dx + \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(x)\cos(nx)dx$$

$$= \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(-x)\cos(-nx)dx + \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(x)\cos(nx)dx$$

$$= -\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(x)\cos(nx)dx + \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(x)\cos(nx)dx = 0$$

wherein the second line we substitute $-x$ for $x$ and change the interval accordingly, and in the third line, we use that it is an odd function to pull out the negative.

Answer (score 3):

For the given integral

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin (x) \cos (nx) \, dx$$

$\sin(x)$ is an odd function while $\cos(nx)$ is an even function. The product of an even and odd function is an odd function. It is well known that the definite integral of an [odd function over a symmetric interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1230999/definite-integral-of-an-odd-function-is-0-symmetric-interval) is zero. Therefore, the integral is zero.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin x = \frac{e^{i x} -e^{-i x}}{2i}$$

$$\cos nx = \frac{e^{i nx} +e^{-i nx}}{2}$$

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin x \cos n x \, dx = \frac{1}{4i} \int_{-\pi}^\pi  \left[e^{i(n+1)x} -e^{-i(n+1)x} + e^{i(1-n)x}-e^{i(n-1)x}\right]\,dx $$

$$=\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left[ \sin (n+1)x -\sin (n-1) x \right] \, dx = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly,

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin x\cos nx dx
= \frac12 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} [\sin (n+1)x -  \sin (n-1)x] dx$$
$$=\frac12\left(-\frac{\cos(n+1)x}{n+1} + \frac{\cos(n-1)x}{n-1}\right)\bigg|_{-\pi}^{\pi}=0$$

Alternatively, $\sin x$ and $\cos nx$ are odd and even functions, respectively. Therefore, the integrand $\sin x\cos nx $ is odd, which leads to vanishing value for the integral.