# How can I use the properties of sin(x) and symmetry to understand this integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This is a true or false question as review for an upcoming exam. My professor states that this integral holds true using symmetry and the fact that sin(y) is an odd function. Can someone please explain how this holds true using those two concepts? I can't wrap my head around how I could ever use symmetry and sin(y) being an odd function to answer this.

T OR F:

$$
\int_{-1}^{1}\int_0^{1} e^{x^2+y^2}sin(y)dxdy=0$$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1230999/definite-integral-of-an-odd-function-is-0-symmetric-interval

Comment: Start by factorizing the double integral as $\int_0^1e^{x^2}\mathrm{d}x\int_{-1}^1e^{y^2}\sin y\mathrm{d}y$.

Comment: You could also swap to polar coordinates. No? @J.G.

Comment: @anonymous For the task at hand, that would be counterproductive.

Comment: You’re right, I just saw it .. due to the $\sin(y)$, right? @J.G.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine plotting the odd function and doing the area to the axis.  The part beneath has negative area and the part above has positive area.

if it's done between $1$ and $-1$ the areas cancel to make $0$.
Here is a plot of the odd function $y=\sin(x)$ from Desmos, to illustrate

[image]

The more complicated equation still has the 'odd' symmetry, negative values have the opposite sign of the positive values

Comment: This makes more sense. So essentially, as long as the 'odd' symmetry exists within the integral and bounds are from a to -a, the integral will always result in 0?

Comment: Also, what if I had an even function alongside an odd function? Does this still hold true?

Comment: Yes, the even parts of the equation don't matter as long as it's odd overall, maybe just watch out for two odd functions multiplied, because then it could go even again

Comment: to check it's odd overall imagine putting two values in e.g. p and -p, if they result in opposite signed values, it'll count as odd

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much!

Comment: Ok, all the best